# Storyboard not changing in iOS simulator

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I'm new to xcode and was making something with xcode using storyboards to try and display a highscore that saves an int with NSUserDefaults, so I created a new view controller for the scores. But the score view acted like the game screen, and has the enemies moving across the screen even though I have a different .h for it.
Since I don't know what I was doing, I changed this (and probably shouldn't have)

```
@interface ViewHighScore : ViewController
```

into

```
@interface ViewHighScore : UIViewController
```

in the .h and the enemies stopped coming down, but now when I add something to the storyboard and run, it doesn't show, no matter what view I'm on. So I changed it back and enemies move across the screen again, but still doesn't change when I run.

Comment: Can you verify in the project -> Targets -> MainStoryBoard that you have a storyBoard ?

Answer (score 0):

First, try opening the View Controller at fault in Storyboard and reset the custom class. Make sure it hasn't changed from `ViewHighScore`.
Your class for the View Controller may have changed because you changed the type.

If that doesn't work, try cleaning your project using the <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> combination.

Comment: All of the views don't update. When I try to add a label, it doesn't show up. I deleted the view and the button that opened it and it didn't change, when I run it's still there. But when I do something like NSLog or change the speed the enemies move, it works, but no new visual things show up.

Answer (score 0):

I've resoulved the same problem. Try removing directory with simulator data ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/